# Сравнение данных в "input" с данными в объекте

Tags: javascript, jquery, объекты

Все было бы прекрасно, но проблема с последним `else if`. 
Он с каждым объектом выдает `alert` независимо значение `true` или `false`.
А мне нужно чтобы выдал один раз когда `false`.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var users = [{
    "name": "A",
    "password": "1"
  }, {
    "name": "B",
    "password": "2"
  }, {
    "name": "C",
    "password": "3"
  }, {
    "name": "D",
    "password": "4"
  }];

  $(document).on("click", ".check-data", function() {
    var CheckName = $('.check-name').val();
    var CheckPassword = $('.check-pass').val();

    for (var i = 0; i < users.length; i++) {
      var DataName = users[i].name;
      var DataPassword = users[i].password;

      if (CheckName === DataName && CheckPassword === DataPassword) {
        alert('Connected');
        break;
      } else if (CheckName === "" && CheckPassword === "") {
        alert('Required to enter a name and password');
        break;
      } else if (CheckName === DataName && CheckPassword === "") {
        alert('Required to enter a password');
        break;
      } else if (CheckName === DataName && CheckPassword !== DataPassword) {
        alert('Wrong password');
        break;
      } else if (CheckName !== DataName) {
        alert('Name not found');
      }
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<form>
  <a>Check Name</a>
  <input class="check-name"></input>
  <br>
  <a>Check Password</a>
  <input class="check-pass" type="password"></input>
  <br>
  <button class="check-data">Check Data in object</button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вы же понимаете, что такой способ авторизации бесполезен на сайте? Любой может открыть исходный код странице и узнать пароль! **Проверка пароля должна производится сервером!**

Но, давайте представим, что этот пример просто для обучения JS.

Вы циклом перебираете значения и производите проверки, которые должны быть на разных этапах?

**Во-первых,** не нужно проверять пустое ли поле, с каждым юзером, проверьте значения перед циклом:

```
 if (CheckName === "" ) {
        alert('Required to enter a name');
        return;;
 } 
 if (CheckPassword === "") {
        alert('Required to enter a password');
        return;;
 }
```

**Во-вторых,** перебирая имена, не надо каждый раз выводить ошибку. Создайте переменную, которая будет фиксировать найден ли пользователь:

```
 var namefound = false;
 for (var i = 0; i < users.length; i++) {
       if (CheckName === DataName) {
            namefound = true;
       }
 ...
```

И если совпадения не произошло, выведите ошибку в конце:

```
 if (!namefound) {
      alert('Name not found');
      return;
 }
```

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var users = [{
    "name": "A",
    "password": "1"
  }, {
    "name": "B",
    "password": "2"
  }, {
    "name": "C",
    "password": "3"
  }, {
    "name": "D",
    "password": "4"
  }];
 
  $(document).on("click", ".check-data", function() {
    var namefound = false;
    var CheckName = $('.check-name').val();
    var CheckPassword = $('.check-pass').val();


    if (CheckName === "") {
      alert('Required to enter a name');
      return;
    } else if (CheckPassword === "") {
      alert('Required to enter a password');
      return;
    }

    for (var i = 0; i < users.length; i++) {
      var DataName = users[i].name;
      var DataPassword = users[i].password;
      if (CheckName === DataName) {
        namefound = true;
      }
      if (CheckName === DataName && CheckPassword === DataPassword) {
        alert('Connected');
        Connected = true;
        break;
      } else if (CheckName === DataName && CheckPassword !== DataPassword) {
        alert('Wrong password');
        return;
      }

    }
    if (!namefound) {
      alert('Name not found');
      return;
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<form>
  <a>Check Name</a>
  <input class="check-name"></input>
  <br>
  <a>Check Password</a>
  <input class="check-pass" type="password"></input>
  <br>
  <button class="check-data">Check Data in object</button>
</form>
```

Comment: `exit`? функция которая должна запускаться в конце?

Comment: @DimenSi я не знаю, что планирует автор вопроса делать после всей проверки, потому на всякий случай `exit`

Comment: Ну поставьте exit(), а то я например не мог понять существует такой оператор или это функция :) А у меня 2-3 месяца опыта в js

Comment: Действительно, спутал с php. Странно что работает все. Заменил на `return;`

Comment: Большое спасибо за советы!

Comment: Я учусь как создать форму, сохранить данные в localstorage, ( потому что, пока я не умею работать с базами данных). И создать вход. Я учусь html, css, javascript. Простите за моего русского языка. Очень помогли!

Comment: @Nerijus Наш сайт отличается от социальных сетей. Он помогает решать прикладные задачи. Поэтому мы используем комментарии только по делу — уточнить проблему, дать конструктивную критику или добавить полезную информацию.

Чтобы поблагодарить автора ответа, проголосуйте за ответ или отметьте его как решение. http://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Answer (score 0):

Вы `break` забыли написать, из-за чего цикл не прерывается.

Имхо, называйте переменные по другому. CheckName вводит заблуждение, кажется, что это функция которая проверяет имя. Можете например testedName или просто name.